# volume calculation using fortran

Tags: fortran

I am trying to calculate the volume of this arbitrary shape.
I am trying to do it with arrays;

```
REAL, DIMENSION(2) :: A,B,C,D,E
REAL :: Area
A = (/ -3, -2 /)
B = (/ -1,4 /)
C =  (/ 6,1 /)
D = (/ 3,10 /)
E = (/ -4,9 /)
Area =  abs((A(1)*B(2)+B(1)*C(2)+C(1)*D(2)+D(1)*E(2)+E(1)*A(2))-(B(1)*A(2)+C(1)*B(2)+D(1)*C(2)+E(1)*D(2)+E(2)*A(1)))/2
Print*,Area
stop
end
```

is it correct way to do it? It seems to me like tons of basic math. 
Any suggestion would be perfect!

[image: Image url]

Comment: It's the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest you take the [tour.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)This question is not really about Fortran programming and belongs on another site. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Just create a single 2D array for all the points and rewrite it to a for loop.

Comment: as a side-note, Fortran standard >2003 has the new array constructor `[ ]` instead of the ugly old `(/ /)`